# Google Sheets App Script: Conditional hide or show columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dynamic, formatting

I am trying to hide or show values based on values in column A3:A.

Essentialy, loop through all the sheets, if the value in column A is "HIDE", hide the row. And if the value in column A is "SHOW", then show the row. Currently running it from at button on the setup page.

- Loop through all sheets

  - Loop through the cells of row A of the sheet

    - IF cell contains "HIDE", hide the row
    - IF cell contains "SHOW", show the row

My original attempt:

```
function fourthTry(){
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var rowsToCheck = 198;
  var columnsToCheck = 1;

  // ** Loop Through every sheet **
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++ ){
    Logger.log("i: " + i)
    var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    // ** Loop through every cell in Row A **
      
      for (var j=0; j < rowsToCheck ;  j++){
        Logger.log("j: " + j);
        var range = activeSheet.getRange(rowsToCheck,columnsToCheck);
        var rangeValue = range.getValue();
        Logger.log("rangeValue: " + rangeValue);

        // IF cell contains HIDE, hiderow
        if(rangeValue == "HIDE"){
          Logger.log("Hidden value: " + rangeValue);
        }
        // IF cell contains SHOW, showrow

      }

  }
```

I'm also open to a completely different approach, as long as it hides and shows columns based on text in row A of all the sheets.

[The Setup Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHJOF.jpg)

[Structure of the page where I want to hide columns based on value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuFqJ.jpg)

**Fixed code based on answers:

```
/** 
* TITLE:
*     Hide a row if row 1 contains the text "HIDE" 
*     Show a row if row 1 contains the text "SHOW"
*/

function UpdateCategories(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  // ** Loop Through every sheet **
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++ ){


    var lastRow = sheets[i].getLastRow();

    var activeSheet = sheets[i];
    Logger.log("===== " + activeSheet.getSheetName() + " =====");


    // ** Loop through every cell in Row A **
      for (var j=1; j < lastRow ;  j++){
        var range = activeSheet.getRange(j,1);
        var rangeValue = range.getValue();
        //Logger.log(j + ". " + rangeValue);

        // IF cell contains HIDE, hiderow
        if(rangeValue == "HIDE"){
          //Logger.log(j + ". " + rangeValue);
          activeSheet.hideRows(j);
        }

        if(rangeValue == "SHOW"){
          //Logger.log(j + ". " + rangeValue);
          activeSheet.showRows(j);
        }
        // IF cell contains SHOW, showrow
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome, TheDavidDelight!  Can you clarify why the "Show" option is needed?  By default, won't all the rows be showing, unless they get hidden by this script because they have "Hide" in column A?  Unless you have another script that is putting "Show" in the hidden rows, but not unhiding them at the same time.  Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: This is for a template. So on the setup page, you can fill inn categories and subcategories.
This fills different pages with the values from the setup page.
I want to hide the empty rows, so I have made a conditional cell in the A column that checks diffferent values and returns either "show" or "hide".
I also want it to be possible to add more categories later, hence the script should be able to both show and hide based on the value. If that makes sense?

Comment: Don’t use active sheet in your loop. Use sheets[i] instead.

Comment: I would not use a fixed number of rows but sheets[i].getLasrRow() instead

Comment: Good feedback so far, I have fixed the code above to reflect what you said.

I'm suspecting that my problem might have something to do with these lines:
`
        var range = activeSheet.getRange(rowsToCheck,columnsToCheck);
        var rangeValue = range.getValue();
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here: `var range = activeSheet.getRange(rowsToCheck,columnsToCheck);`

It's always `var range = activeSheet.getRange(lastrow,1);` but it needs to be iterating through the rows. So it needs to be something like this:

`var range = activeSheet.getRange(i+startrow,1);`  whatever your start row is for data.  There are quicker ways to iterate through the data with setValues() but I'll leave that for you to investigate on your own

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That fixes my main problem.
Only thing I'm missing now is the code inside

if(rangeValue == "SHOW"). 

they have a .hideRow(range) but not an equivalent .showRow(range). Any thought on how I could solve this?

Comment: I figured it out, thank you very much! :)