# Macro to hide/show columns based on color (or text)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How would you automatically hide/unhide an array of disconnected columns (not grouped or next to each other) based on an attribute like cell color or contained text? My end goal is to enable a user to see either all "Projected" or "Actual" columns in a cash flow document: ([image: screenshot])

I did not see any baked in utility that does this. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65760848/google-sheets-app-script-conditional-hide-or-show-columns) also does not work correctly.

```html
function UpdateCategories(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  // ** Loop Through every sheet **
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++ ){


    var lastRow = sheets[i].getLastRow();

    var activeSheet = sheets[i];
    Logger.log("===== " + activeSheet.getSheetName() + " =====");


    // ** Loop through every cell in Row 3 **
      for (var j=3; j < lastRow ;  j++){
        var range = activeSheet.getRange(j,3);
        var rangeValue = range.getValue();
        //Logger.log(j + ". " + rangeValue);

        // IF cell contains Projected, hidecolumn
        if(rangeValue == "Projected"){
          //Logger.log(j + ". " + rangeValue);
          activeSheet.hideColumns(j);
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried.  Whenever is possible avoid the use of images; when posting sample data, add it as text, you might use markdown to format it as table.

Comment: Although unfortunately, I'm not sure about your actual Spreadsheet because I cannot see the information of the rows and columns you expect, by guessing your situation, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your actual situation and that was not useful, I apologize. At that time, can you provide more information for understanding your situation? By this, I would like to modify the sample script.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- From `My end goal is to enable a user to see either all "Projected" or "Actual" columns in a cash flow document:`, for example, you want to hide the columns that the value of the header row (row 3?) is "Projected" or "Actual".
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In your script, it seems that the row values are checked. From your question, I thought that you might have wanted to check the header row. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, please set the variables of `headerRow`, `startColumn` and `sheetNames` for your actual situation, and save the script.

```js
function sample_(hide) {
  var headerRow = 3; // Header row including "Actual" and "Projected".
  var startColumn = 1; // Start the column number you want to use. In this sample, the columns are scanned from column "A".
  var sheetNames = ["Sheet1",,,]; // Sheet names you want to use this script.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    if (!sheetNames.includes(sheet.getSheetName())) continue;
    var cols = sheet.getLastColumn() - startColumn + 1;
    var header = sheet.getRange(headerRow, startColumn, 1, cols).getDisplayValues()[0];
    sheet.showColumns(startColumn, cols);
    header.forEach((h, j) => {
      if (h == hide) {
        sheet.hideColumns(j + startColumn);
      }
    });
  }
}

function hideProjectedColumns() {
  sample_("Projected");
}

function hideActualColumns() {
  sample_("Actual");
}
```

- In this sample, when `hideProjectedColumns()` is run, the columns with the value of "Projected" in the header row are hidden. When `hideActualColumns()` is run, the columns with the value of "Actual" in the header row are hidden.

#### References:

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [hideColumns(columnIndex, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=ja#hidecolumnscolumnindex,-numcolumns)